Sharepoint discussion board user mark read list
I am posting various reports on discussion board and needed to check from time to time if certain member have read the post, I am now using a table and allow user to edit if they have read the post and want to see if there is better way so that I can check user list who have read the post and remind users who havent read the post, thanks in advance


Display the post title with "read more" link.
When user clicks on read more link, get the logged in user email, post Id and store in backend list / db table.
Do check if any entry for the same post and
user is already available, if not create a new entry,
this way you can handle the duplicate view count.

